# tracking clicks on links that will unload the page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I see my coworker adding tracking code like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/shop" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Site Promos', 'Bottom_pos1', 'Bookstore Promo']);">See all&nbsp;»</a>
```

but AFAIK this is incorrect - right? As this JS code will dispatch another HTTP tracking request while browser just get's redirected to "http://www.example.com/shop". So if tracking request doesn't finish before browser opens to  www.example.com/shop -> nothing will get tracked.

How should I track clicks correctly?

Comment: first off, don't use inline js

Comment: OK - sure. But also I need a callback - right? Just like in here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en

Comment: @AmitJoki - what is wrong with inline js in this case?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, everything

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the way the code is structured will in most cases not actually send the request the GA for tracking.

Since you are using "classic" GA (ga.js), you don't have the option of the callback, you could do something like this instead.

```
function gotoUrl(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
}

function trackGAEvent(action, label, value, url) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', action, label, value]);

  setTimeout("gotoUrl('" + url+ "')", 100);
}

<a href="http://www.example.com/shop" 
      onClick="trackGAEvent('Site Promos', 'Bottom_pos1', 'Bookstore Promo',
      this.href);return false;">See all&nbsp;»</a>
```